# Python2.7: No module named zlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, module, zlib

I'm trying to use **matplotlib** in Python 2.7, but am encountering the following error

```
    >>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 156, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 9, in <module>
    import zlib
ImportError: No module named zlib
```

I installed python with `sudo apt-get install python2.7`, and other required packages similarly. I installed **zlib** from source, with no issues.

Comment: Have you tried to import zlib in python interactive session?

Comment: zlib is a dependency of `matplotlib`, you will have to install it

Comment: I have already installed zlib, and import zlib in an interactive session simply gives `ImportError: No module named zlib`. When trying to import zlib, is python looking for something like zlib.py?

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python installed ? Did you use `pip`, `conda` or `easy_install` to install the packages ?

Comment: Yeah, I have 3.4 as well, but I'm using 2.7 to run the interactive session (checked with `sys`). Nope, used apt-get for all packages.